# How can I iterate through a list of projects to add example files to a newly created Gitlab project with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gitlab

I am managing a project structure in Gitlab using Terraform. The projects are maintained in the `terraform.tfvars` in a map:

```
applications = {
  "Test App" = {
    content_owner = "email@adress"
    org_code      = "AA BB CC"
  },
  "App 2" = {
    content_owner = "email@adress"
    org_code      = "AA BB CC"
  },
  "App 3" = {
    content_owner = "email@adress"
    org_code      = "AA BB CC"
  }
}
```

As a starter, I want to create a branch in every project and commit some sample files into it using the [repository file] resource (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs/resources/repository_file).

In pseudo code I need something like: "For each `applications` go through all of the files in `fileset("../templates/sample-application", "**/*.*")` and create a file in the branch"

I tried several variations of `for_each`, `setproduct` etc. without success.

```
resource "gitlab_project" "project" {
  for_each     = var.applications
  name         = each.key
  namespace_id = 12345
  description  = "App GUID: ${random_uuid.app_id[each.key].result}, Content owner: ${each.value.content_owner} (${each.value.org_code})"

  allow_merge_on_skipped_pipeline                  = false
  container_registry_enabled                       = false
  initialize_with_readme                           = true
  issues_enabled                                   = false
  lfs_enabled                                      = true
  merge_method                                     = "merge"
  merge_requests_enabled                           = true
  only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved = true
  only_allow_merge_if_pipeline_succeeds            = true
  packages_enabled                                 = false
  pipelines_enabled                                = true
  printing_merge_request_link_enabled              = true
  shared_runners_enabled                           = true
  visibility_level                                 = "private"
  wiki_enabled                                     = false
}

... 

resource "gitlab_branch" "sample_application" {
  for_each = var.applications
  name     = "sample-application"
  ref      = "main"
  project  = gitlab_project.project[each.key].id
}

...

resource "gitlab_repository_file" "sample_application" {
  for_each       = ???
  project        = gitlab_project.project.???
  file_path      = ???
  branch         = "sample-application"
  content        = filebase64("../templates/sample-application/${???}")
  author_email   = "email@address"
  author_name    = "Terraform"
  commit_message = "chore: add sample application"
}
```

Please shine some light on this.

Thanks!

Comment: And why not use the same variable in `for_each` for the `gitlab_repository_file` as well? Are there any errors?

Comment: Because I need basically two `for_each`: one for the projects and one for the files that need to be uploaded - this makes it complicated.

Comment: Can you name the files you want the same way you name the project?

Comment: Unfortunately not, example:

```text
➜  sample-application git:(main) ✗ find .
.
./favicon.ico
./index.html
./css
./css/main.css
./css/normalize.css
./js
./js/plugins.js
./js/main.js
./js/vendor
./js/vendor/modernizr-3.11.2.min.js
./404.html
./README.md
./img
./img/icon.png
./img/tile-wide.png
./img/tile.png
./.gitignore
./manifest.json
./.gitlab-ci.yml
./browserconfig.xml
```

Comment: Are the files different per sample application? Where are the files located relative to the terraform code?

Comment: Have you considered creating the projects from a template containing those files instead by specifying the [`template_project_id`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs/resources/project#template_project_id)? That way all the files will just be there when the project is created.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use custom templates, so this option is out :-(

Comment: The files are all the same for all projects and are relative (see above `../templates/sample-application`)